# Query Remote Windows Service through PHP

Tags: php, windows, web

The following PHP **win32_query_service_status** works for querying the local machine, however we are attempting to perform this query on a remote machine within the same domain. We receive no errors however nothing is returned ideas?

```
 $name = "spooler"
 $machine = "remotemachine"
         $status=win32_query_service_status($name, $machine);

         echo "$name service is ";
         if ($status["CurrentState"]==1) {echo "Stopped";}
         else
         if ($status["CurrentState"]==2) {echo "Starting";}
         else
         if ($status["CurrentState"]==3) {echo "Stopping";}
         else
         if ($status["CurrentState"]==4) {echo "Running";}
```